# jQuery select index of dropdownlist based upon number of elements and value of current selection

Tags: jquery, select, drop-down-menu

I have a form with multiple dropdownlists on it.  Some of them possess multiple values, others posess a blank choice and another random choice.

Using jQuery how do I detect which dropdowns have the blank choice selected AND have only one other choice THEN select that other choice.

I got the selector part down,

```
$("[id*='_ddl']").each(function() {
```

but am not sure how to detect the number of choices available, and if the currently selected value is a blank.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('select[id*=_ddl]').each(function() {
    var itemCount = $('option', this).length;
    var selectedText = $('option:selected', this).text();
    if (selectedText.length === 0 && itemCount === 2) {
        // do stuff
    }
});
```

Comment: replace // do stuff

with 

$(this).get(0).selectedIndex = 1; to select the non blank elemen